# How to acces database from other pc with Wamp

Tags: mysql, wamp

I have some data on WAMP server and I tried to put it online, so I can access it from another PC. I am only getting the web page. I was expecting to get the data from the database. With the original PC all is working fine. Can someone point me in the direction, how to view this data and also insert into the MySQL database? I have given the users privileges, though it is not working.

[The original PC shows this data, the other pc shows only the web page. Inserterting, deleting and updating data is not possible][grant privileges]

Comment: Please put some effort into formatting your question. It's unreadable. Also, please read [ask] and [mcve] to get you started

Comment: Am I right that you are running a web page on this other PC. Or are you trying to use `phpMyAdmin` or some other direct access mechanism to get to your database

Comment: yes. the problem is that it is showing me only the structure of the page. no data. in some other pc it doesnt even show the css and javascript